# Aligning Div Images Horizontally - Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: css, html, flash-cs5

```
 <style type="text/css">

      div.imageSub { position: relative; }
      div.imageSub img { z-index: 1; }
      div.imageSub div {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15%;
        right: 15%;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 4px;
      }
      div.imageSub div.blackbg {
        z-index: 2;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #000;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      div.imageSub div.label {
        z-index: 3;
        color: white;
      }


     </style>
     <body>
      <div class="imageSub" style="width: 300px;"> <!-- Put Your Image Width -->
        <a href="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/stem studio.html"><img   
        src="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/PIC.jpg" alt="Something" width="300" 
        height="437" /></a>
        <div class="blackbg">Hello</div>
        <div class="label"> The Wolf</div>
     </div><br />
    <div class="imageSub" style="width: 300px;"> <!-- Put Your Image Width --><img    
    src="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/PIC.jpg" alt="Something" width="300" height="437"
      />

        <div class="blackbg">Hello</div>
        <div class="label"> The Wolf</div>


  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I am trying to align the two div images horizontally.

I borrowed the code for overlaying text on images from this website :

I just added a random pic and text to see if this code works, It works like perfectly well, but they come out vertically.  How do I align them horizontally ?  Will appreciate any help.

Comment: I am actually trying to obtain a 2 x 3 table. with image and overlaying text in each box. Each one of them will be a tab linking to a page. Here is a quick visual:http://oi50.tinypic.com/2ccqa0l.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you need to have both images side by side. If so, you need to adjust your `CSS` and `HTML` to allow that:

See this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DT8py/)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageSub" style="width: 300px;">
  <a href="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/stem studio.html">
    <img src="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/PIC.jpg" alt="Something" width="300" height="437" />
  </a>
  <div class="blackbg">Hello</div>
  <div class="label"> The Wolf</div>
</div>
<div class="imageSub" style="width: 300px;">
  <img src="../../../Downloads/Unnamed Site 2/PIC.jpg" alt="Something" width="300" height="437" />
  <div class="blackbg">Hello</div>
  <div class="label"> The Wolf</div>
</div>
```

*Removed the `<br>`*

---

**CSS**

```
div.imageSub {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
div.imageSub img {
  z-index: 1;
}
div.imageSub div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}
div.imageSub div.blackbg {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #000;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.imageSub div.label {
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
}
```

*Added `float: left;` to the `div.imageSub`*

## EDITED

A working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DT8py/1/) based on the previous fix, adapted for a 3x2 visual presentation.

Comment: Thank you, Zuul. 

I am actually trying to obtain a 2 x 3 table. with image and overlaying text in each box. Each one of them will be a tab linking to a page. Here is a quick visual:http://oi50.tinypic.com/2ccqa0l.jpg

Comment: @user1413772, just added at the bottom of my answer an example based on the previous fix for the 3x2 presentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `<br/>`
2. Add css rules

   ```
   .imageSub { float: left;}
   .clear { clear: both; }
   ```
3. Add `<div class="clear"/>` to the end.

Don't forget step 3 in floating environments.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rswC/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple a 2 x 3 div solution using floats: http://jsfiddle.net/Fb6Jk/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot !  But is there way to have an overlay text using float ? I mean can you modify for the text to appear on the image ? I will really appreciate it!